# How to construct a linear map from floats in [0,1] to integers in [0,255]?

Tags: math

I need to convert a 32 bit floating point value `x` in the range [0,1] to an 8 bit unsigned integer `y` in the range [0,255].

A formula I found in some C code is : `y = (uint8)(255.99998f*x)`.

This provides the required conversion, but there is a problem with it.

Conversion of 0.75 yield 191, and conversion of 0.25 yields 63. While 0.75+0.25 = 1, 191+63 = 254 and not the desired 255.

Same problem with 0.5 that is converted into 127. 0.5 + 0.5 = 1 and 127+127= 254 instead of 255.

There is thus a rounding error.

Can this be avoided ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Where did those fraction part come from? I do not understand.

Comment: You'll always end up with some sort of rounding error. How would you want to represent `0.5` as an *integer* value such that the sum of two such values gives an ***odd*** number? Let me know if you find a solution - I can sell it!

Comment: To match 255 exactly, `0.5` would need to be converted to `127.5`. This can never happen with integers for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Adrian, so your answer is no, this can’t be avoided ?

Comment: @chmike Possibly. But it depends on the ***exact*** nature of your floating point range. Is it actually `0 <= x < 1` (i.e. can never be actually 1 but can be zero)? If that **is** the range, then `y = (uint8)(256f*x);` will work.

Comment: @Gerhardh if I converted into 16bit unsigned integer, perform the addition, then convert to 8 bit unsigned integer with a right shift after adding 128, would that avoid the problem ?

Comment: @AdrianMole it can be 1. So the range is 0 <= x <= 1 which was I meant by [0,1] instead of [0,1[ as you suggest. I could eventually do `y  = (uint16)(256f*a)` and `if a == 256` set it to 255 and down cast to `uint8.

Comment: @J...: `round(255*x)` does not give the desired property that the mapping f satisfy f(.5) + f(.5) = f(1). OP’s request is not solvable, so this is not simple. No mapping satisfies their stated requirements. When the impossible requirement is removed, there are multiple mappings possible, and you have stated no reason why `round(255*x)` should be preferred. That formula gives short shrift to 0 and 255, so some a solution that spreads the distribution more evenly may be preferred in some applications.

Comment: @J...: Yes, so your “solution” is not a solution.

Comment: @J... That is not correct. The range 0 to 1 included should yield 256 parts, but 1 can’t yield 256. So the formula is correct. It seam the problem has no solution.

Comment: @J...: It is certainly not the only correct answer. `floor(x*16777215/16777216*256)` is another option.

Comment: You really need to specify the mapping.  It appears that you want a linear mapping with 0 going to 0 and 1 going to 255 and everything mapping to the nearest neighbor, but you need to clarify.  As asked, a perfectly valid solution is to map everything to 0.

Comment: @J...: Re “What matters is…”: You do not know what matters; it is not stated in the question.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I disagree. As I said, when 0.5 + 0.5 = 1, I was asking if I could have 127 + 127 = 255 which is obviously not possible. Mapping everything to 0 will never yield 255.

Comment: @J...: There are other options, and you have not stated any valid reason why `round(255*x)` should be preferred.

Comment: @chmike That is only if you specify it as a requirement.  The current question is "How to convert a 32 bit float value in the range [0,1] in an 8 bit unsigned integer [0,255]?".  The question you intended to ask is "How to construct a linear map from floats in [0,1] to integers in [0,255]?"

Comment: @J...: In what sense is it the most accurate? What metric for error are you using?

Comment: @WilliamPursell you are right. I’ll fix the question and remove the C tag since it is not a programming question.

Comment: @J... the formula is mathematically correct considering the floating point precision limitation. By multiplying with 255.99998, I map [0,1] into [0,256[ with the best resolution I can get. I then use the `floor()` function since this is what the conversion to unsigned int does in C.

Comment: Is this for converting pixel/image values or something else?

Comment: @chmike It is not idiomatic, however - this would fall under the general category of *performance hack*, and it's the kind of thing you tend to prefer to avoid unless you have a specific need for it.  If that's the case, then the title of this question needs to change to "*What is the most performant way to map...*"

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes this formula is used to convert a floating point gray map into a uint8 gray map. The floating point gray map is the product of a raster process with antialiasing. What worried me is that operations on the uint8 gray map would yield inaccurate result. But I understand now that this is normal and due to the limited resolution. To avoid such type of errors it is thus preferable to use a uint16 gray map and only convert to uint8 when outputting the result whether on screen on into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Same problem with 0.5 that is converted into 127. 0.5 + 0.5 = 1 and 127+127= 254 instead of 255.

No mapping can satisfy this requirement since `255/2` is not representable as an integer.  You have to decide what this mapping means to you and what properties it requires, but no mapping to integers can satisfy this.

If you choose a floor mapping as you've shown in your question, then `0.5f->127`, in which case your algorithm or program might interpret this to *define the range* of `[0-127]` with 128 elements - exactly half of the 256 elements in `[0-255]`, since the remaining range [128-255] also has 128 elements.

If, however, you choose an analytical mapping like

```
 y = round(255*x);
```

this provides the most accurate numerical value - the value of the output will always be the closest integer to the input value. For a value of `0.5f`, this produces `128`, which is exactly half of the number of bins in the output range.  In this case your algorithm might interpret this as the *number of elements* in the range which is half of the input range.  It's really up to you to design the algorithm and interpretation of the mapping around the limitations imposed by discarding the resolution of a 32-bit float.

Ultimately, `[0.0-1.0]` is about measuring something and `[0-255]` is about counting something... only you know what you're measuring and what you're counting so we can't really make this decision for you.

If your application is one which is measurement-like, then `round(255*x)` will produce the closest integer to the input float - a value of `0.0039062`, for example, is within 0.001% of a perfect map to `1`, will map to 1.

If your application is one which is counting-like, and you are more interested in *equally binning* the float values, then a floor mapping (like your original suggestion) will map an equal range of the input to each bin.  Using the `round` equation will leave the `0` bin and the `255` bin mapped to half the range of the rest of the bins.  Using a floor mapping produces an equal distribution of the input range to the output bins, but sacrifices numerical precision.  The above example of a value of `0.0039062`, for example, would map to `0` in this case, even though it's 99.99% of the value you would consider to be `1`.

It's entirely up to you to determine which mapping makes sense for your specific application.

Comment: The conversion from float to int is a `floor()` function. A `round()` function is more expensive to compute. It is a programming question, not just math.

Comment: @chmike Your conversion is using a floor, yes.  Yes, round is more expensive, but you stated no constraints for performance.  Your entire question seemed fixated on the accuracy of the mapping.  This is the mapping you want if you want accuracy.

Comment: A problem I see is that 0 will only get values [0, 0.001960..] instead 1 will get [0.001960.., 0.005882..] that is an interval twice as large; in other words this formula is unfair as 0 and 255 will only get half the cases other numbers will get.

Comment: @6502 I don't think "problem" is the correct word.  It's a feature of the mapping that may be a problem for some algorithms, depending on what you're doing.  OP specified no constraints other than a few misconceptions.  What's above is idiomatic.  Whether it suits OP's purpose, only they can say.

Comment: IIUC the idea was to map "uniformly" and your solution is strongly non-uniform for no good reasons. What is used normally to get a decent distribution is `min(maxval, floor(x*(maxval+1)))`. For example with 4097 float numbers distributed from 0 to 1 uniformly (i/4096. for i from 0 to 4096) your code will return 0 and 255 only 9 times, most values 16 times and bunch of other values 17 times. Using instead `min(255, floor(x*256) )` you get each value covered exactly 16 times except for 255 covered 17 times (of course not perfect as 4097 is not a multiple of 256, but much better).

Comment: @6502 I've expanded the answer somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to represent the closed segment [0.0, 1.0] in an accurate way into the segment [0,255]. The most evident problem is that 0.5 + 0.5 = 1.0 . So if 1.0 is represented by 255, 0.5 cannot be exactly represented.

The real problem is that 32 bits floating point numbers are represented in [IEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) binary 32 format. So you will find a native injection from the [0.0, 1.0[ semi open segment into the [0,255] one by taking the most representative bits of the binary representation (conveniently shifted) and accepting that at the limit 1.0 would be represented as 256.

Then all fractions where the denominator is a power of 2 are exactly represented: 0.5 is 128, 0.25 is 64, and 0.75 is 192 but trying to nicely map [0.0, 1.0] to [0, 255] is close to finding a nice relation from [0,256] (257 values) into [0,255]...